# Methods for choosing cut-offs

Tags: statistics

*Disclaimer:* I am not sure which tags to use here. Please correct if you know.

---

Let's say I have a objects $o_i \in O$ that have a certain attribute $a_i \in [0,1]$. I only want to keep objects with a large $a_i$. A simple way would be to define a threshold $t$ and keep all objects where $a_i > t$. The question remains how to choose $t$.

#### Loss function

The objects are used to build a model from it (clustering in this case).

I would like to retain as few objects as possible while keeping the sum of $a_i$ of the retained objects as large as possible.

#### Questions

- What methods exist to choose such a $t$ in general?
- What methods exist under the assumption that the number of / density of objects is exponentially falling for increasing $a_i$?

A best practice would be nice, but I would even more prefer a scientific and published method, even more if there is a established method.

The method cannot be based on visualization (so no elbow-method), but must be calculable.

Comment: Do you really want as few $o_i$ as possible? If so, why not order the objects by size and take the largest $n$ (or until their cumulative sum is large enough?).

Comment: @Roland: That is what I am doing right now. I set a minimal sum of $a_i$ and take as few objects as possible to reach that. Does not sound too scientific though.

Comment: Well, you have some arbitaryness on the value of the sum, or the number of objects, which is along similar lines of choosing the right $t$. In general, taking as few objects as possible will not lead to very stable models. There should be a way to measure (for example with cross validation or bootstrapping) the effects of varying your parameter (be it the minimal sum, a number or a threshold $t$).

Comment: @Roland: I am developing my own algorithm. Part of it is to choose only a part of the objects as an approximation. So there is no way I can do a cross-validation or something complex like this in this part of the algorithm. Otherwise this will be so computationally expensive, I might as well keep all objects.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a couple key ingredients: what are you doing (action) with the selected $o_i$ and what your loss function for this action. Right now, any $t$ is just as good as any other. Let's say you pick $t=0.7$, how would you rate how good this is?

A common example is if you are evaluating how your choice of $t$ affects the predictive power of a model built using a given value of $t$.

Bottom line: your problem is not specified sufficiently to choose a $t$ apart from subjective preference.

Comment: I updated my question. Did this help?

Comment: @Make42 as written  your loss function isn't a loss function -- it's just a restatement of your question. It needs to quantify the trade off between number of objects and the sum of their attribute values.

Comment: I know it's not a strict loss function. However, if I was able to formulate one, I would be able to find the optimal decision myself. Because I am not having more more information, I am asking my question.

Comment: @Make42 unfortunately, since you are doing clustering, you really are out of luck (if you were doing supervised learning, then you could at least choose $t$ to minimize classification error or something like that). You're basically asking a bunch of strangers to make a subjective decision for you. No published paper will address your specific needs. You need to do the thinking on this one...sorry.

Comment: No problem. But just for the record: If a problem is clearly formulated and it is a standard one (standard = it can be abstracted to a standard problem, which can be solved with a known standard solution), solving it is trivial (at least from a perspective of mathematical engineering, - it might become a computer science issue though). If you have a loss function, just plug it into a solver. The issue becomes interesting if you need to find a suitable loss function - often this is the challenge in mathematical engineering. My 50cents to the scientific philosophical side of the matter ;-)

Comment: @Make42 I agree - but as formulated, your problem doesn't admit any loss function. You want two opposing things and have not considered possible balancing criteria. If you had some criteria, then you'd have the raw stuff for devising a loss function. You can't have "fewest units for the most X", you need to think about what you are balancing against. Perhaps computation time? Some measure of clustering (e.g, how well separated the units are?)...you need to know what you want out of clustering to at least start to develop a loss function.